# Intellij idea use docker-compose can't mappeed native file to the remote docker

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I just want to deploy my springboot applicaiton on the remote centos server through the intellij idea.
First I tried the way of DockerFile to deploy the application on intellij idea and I successed.
this is my DockerFile config

```
FROM williamyeh/java8

# COPY or ADD to image
COPY dockerdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
 
RUN bash -c "touch /app.jar"

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

but when I tried the method of docker-compose.yml,I failed,I can't mapped my navtive jar to the remote system.my docker-compose.yml config is

```
version: "3"
services:
  dockerDemo2:
    image: adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:latest
    container_name: dockerDemo2
    privileged: true
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Shanghai
      LANG: es_US.UTF-8
    volumes:
      - ./dockerdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/docker/dockerdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    command: bash -c "  tail -f /dev/null "
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

[image: docker-compose.yml deployed successed]

I deployed successed,but when I get in the remote docker ,I found the /docker/dockerdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is a directory, It should expected as a jar file,but it not,I don't know why that.that's really confuesed me.

[image: the remote centos server docker]

Comment: Just copy the file like you did with `app.jar`. Volumes are supposed to be directories.

Comment: I tried,but the result is the empty folder was copied to the remote docker, there is nothing in the same name directories on docker,my native system is windows 10 ,and I used the docker-compose.exe of Docker Desktop for windows,the file can't be  awared by the docker-compose volumes.whatever I chanaged the path and filename ,it always be empty folder in docker

Comment: Please rephrase your title to summarize your specific problem, so by browsing the list of questions one easily understands what your question is about!

Comment: ok,I have changed  the title and make it more specific describtion of my question